# Kylin cube builds successfully but its size is shown as 0 KB

Tags: hbase, kylin

I have installed apache kylin on hadoop client machine. I have created data model and cube successfully. cube build is also successful but when I go to models tab it shows cube's size as 0 KB. When I go to the insights tab, I can query the dimension tables properly but when I query the fact table it returns 0 records.

The query that kylin uses to fetch data returns records when I execute it on hive which means that there is no problem with the data itself. However, the hbase table that kylin creates for cube have a very few records compared to the original fact table. I am guessing that kylin may have some compatibility issue with hbase. Can anybody give any insights on this?

**Hadoop v2.9.0
Hbase  v1.2.6.1
Kylin  v2.3.1**

Cube size is 0 KB. Storage is less than 1MB:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we scan the HBase table in HBase shell to see whether it has data.

If the HBase table is 0 record, that means no Cube data. If you're sure the Hive intermediate table has data, there is no reason the Cube is empty. Just check the log to see whether there is something went wrong.